# Eliminar múltiples carácteres de un string

Tags: java, eclipse

Quiero eliminar los últimos caracteres de un String. En este caso, los últimos 4. Los String son: `www.google.es.txt` y `www.youtube.es.txt`. La funcionalidad de mi programa es abrir estas 2 url, pero obviamente, eliminando antes es ".txt".

Comment: Buen día, recuerda que al hacer una pregunta es importante incluir tu código para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Guillemj lo que puedes hacer es un Replace, esto te remplazara lo que quieras por nada así lo eliminas.

```
const p = 'www.google.es.txt';
p = p.replace('.txt', '');
```

La otra opción es decirle que lea el string menos lo últimos caracteres seria así:

```
const p = 'www.google.es.txt';
p = p.substring(0, p.length() - 4);
```